# Storing results of fitdist

Tags: r

I'm running a distribution fitting analysis to my data. I'm trying 5 different distributions and I'd like to store the results for each one in an array or matrix.
So I'm using the fitdist function of the fitdistrplus package and all goes well, but I don't know how to save each result. This is a newbie question but I've googled several times and no useful result came up.

Current code:

```
for loop
    .....
    params = fitdist( data, dist,method="mle")
    print( params )
    summary( params ) 
    plot( params )
```

So I need something like:

```
for loop
    .....
    params = fitdist( data, dist,method="mle")
    result1[i]<-print( params ) #Can I save a print (graphics)?
    result2[i]<-summary( params ) 
    result3[i]<-plot( params )
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just save the `params` object itself. `result1[i]<-params`. Then run other stuff on it later: `summary(result1[i])`.

Comment: Hi! if I use result1[i]<-params I get "object 'result1' not found" and if I use result1[i]<-params I get "function 'result1' not found". I think I have to do something first for it to accept the code.

Comment: did you predefine `result1`? e.g. `result1 <- list()`, prior to entering in the loop? then maybe use `result1[[i]]` instead of `result1[i]`

Comment: No I didn't predefine result1.

Comment: just use result1[i]<-matrix() at the start!

Comment: Notice the -2 votes. You do not indicate what package `fitdist` comes from , and do not construct an actual example. It was easy enough to give a high level answer that address some of the obvious issues, but R programmers are a very concrete crowd. We need real data and real code to work on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(You *should* offer an example of how you are representing 'data' and 'dist'.)

You need to predefine the result items because R will not automatically accept `resutl1[i]<-` inside a loop if `result1` doesn't already exist. This assumes that 'data' and 'distr' are lists or vectors of appropriate type for `fitdistr`. It's possible that you may need to use "[[" instead of "[" (or a combination) in the arguments to `fitdistr`.

```
result1<-result2<-result3<-list()
for (i in seq_along(data) ) 
   {
    params = fitdist( data[i], dist[i], method="mle")
    result1[i]<-print( params )
     #Can I save a print (graphics)?
     # You can save lattice and ggplot2 graphics as list objects but I think `fitdistr`
     # may use base graphics which cannot be saved unless you use a file graphics device
    result2[i]<-summary( params ) 
    result3[i]<-plot( params )
   }
```

You would access the result objects using `results[[i]]` rather than `results[i]` since "[[" extracts the actual value in a list, while `results[i]` would give you a sublist with one element. If might be better (more compact and ultimately more flexible) to save just the 'params' objects to which you could later apply `summary()` and `print()` as needed.

Comment: By `fitdistr` (MASS?) you mean `fitdist`?

Comment: When I wrote it I was assuming (incorrectly) jpcgandre was using MASS::fitdistr, but my advice was really generic rather than focused on the particular type of functional value.

Answer (score 0):

just use `result1[i]<-matrix()` at the start!

Comment: If `fitdistr` returns a list (as it is likely to be, since most new R users would be using `MASS::fitditr`) then assignment to a matrix would not be the most natural approach for R programmers, although it would be possible to do.